# Testcontainers not working in AWS Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-codebuild, cicd, testcontainers

I have spring boot application which uses testcontainers to run tests. All the tests are running locally but when I tried in AWS Codebuild project, it is failing. Looks like it is unable to connect to database.
This is my buildspec.yml file for codebuild.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - export ROOT_DIR=$PWD
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Starting build at `date`
      - cd $ROOT_DIR && ./gradlew integrationTest
```

I am getting following error when running ./gradlew integrationTest

```
UserServiceIT > assertThatResetKeyMustBeValid() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786
            Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException at HikariPool.java:595
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at Preconditions.java:174
```

Getting above exception for every test. I have tried **TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true** but still not working.

Comment: We need logs and the code that uses Testcontainers to understand the issue.

Comment: We recently update the docs adding AWS CodeBuild https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/aws_codebuild/

Comment: have you been able to find what was the issue?